# error: prototype for 'EM::EM(...)' does not match any in class 'EM'

Tags: c++

after I declared the class in the .h file and was working i added some functions and libraries then this error came out !

> (error: prototype for 'EMPLOYE::EMPLOYE(std::string, int, int)' does not match any in class 'EMPLOYE')

and here's the two files

PRJET.h

```
#ifndef PRJET_h
#define PRJET_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class EMPLOYE{
protected:
string nom;
int matricule,indice;
static int valeur ;

public:
Employe(string , int, int);
void afficher();
int salaire();
};

class RESPONSABLE : public EMPLOYE{
protected:
EMPLOYE SUBORDONE[];
string responsable;

public:
Responsable(string,string,int,EMPLOYE[],string);


//bool verifierEmploye(int){};
//void ajouterEmploye(Employe){};
//void afficheEmploye(){};



};
#endif // date_H
```

PRJET.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PRJET.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

EMPLOYE::EMPLOYE(string n , int m ,int i){
nom=n;
matricule=m;
indice=i;
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning variables in the constructor body rather than using the constructors initialization list? Seems weird and is inefficient.

Comment: Compare `Employe(string , int, int)` and `EMPLOYE::EMPLOYE(string n , int m ,int i)`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is case-sensitive.

The name `EMPLOYE` and the name `Employe` are *two different names*.

Thus, you did not ever actually declare a constructor for `EMPLOYE`, confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has no user-defined constructors, should be this instead:

```
class EMPLOYE{
protected:
string nom;
int matricule,indice;
static int valeur ;

public:
EMPLOYE(string , int, int);
void afficher();
int salaire();
};
```

P.S.: It is extremely weird to have type names in ALL CAPS, goes against the language conventions.